# How to render 1000+ 2d text labels using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a floor plan, i have more than 1000 2d meshes (shapeGeometry + basicMeshMaterial) on the scene and also i want to put 2d text inside them, i need this text to be overflow hidden by bounds of mesh.

I tried to use TextGeometry, troika-three-text, CSS2dRenderer, but all of them had a bad performance with 1000 of elements.
Could you advice me please a best approach of rendering so big bunch of text ?

What I have right now (several elements): [example](https://three-ncjav6vvy-zakablukov777.vercel.app/floorplan)
What I have right now (a lot of elements): [example](https://three-ncjav6vvy-zakablukov777.vercel.app/floorplan/16568)
Example of what i want to get https://demo.expofp.com/

Answer (score 5):

As an option, use instancing.

`InstancedBufferGeometry` of `PlaneGeometry`, with a texture atlas, can help.

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.153.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.153.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
console.clear();

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xface8d);
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(3, 5, 8).setLength(40);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
//renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());

let ig = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry().copy(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 1));
ig.instanceCount = Infinity;
const amount = 2048;
let instPos = new Float32Array(amount * 3);
for(let i = 0; i < amount;i++){
  instPos[i * 3 + 0] = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(50);
  instPos[i * 3 + 1] = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(50);
  instPos[i * 3 + 2] = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(50);
}
ig.setAttribute("instPos", new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(instPos, 3));

let im = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    quaternion: {value: new THREE.Quaternion()},
    markerTexture: {value: getMarkerTexture(4096, 32, 64)},
    textureDimensions: {value: new THREE.Vector2(32, 64)}
  },
  vertexShader: `
    uniform vec4 quaternion;
    uniform vec2 textureDimensions;
    
    attribute vec3 instPos;
    
    varying vec2 vUv;
    
    vec3 qtransform( vec4 q, vec3 v ){ 
      return v + 2.0*cross(cross(v, q.xyz ) + q.w*v, q.xyz);
    } 
    
    void main(){
      vec3 pos = qtransform(quaternion, position) + instPos;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.);
      
      float iID = float(gl_InstanceID);
      float stepW = 1. / textureDimensions.x;
      float stepH = 1. / textureDimensions.y;
      
      float uvX = mod(iID, textureDimensions.x);
      float uvY = floor(iID / textureDimensions.x);
      
      vUv = (vec2(uvX, uvY) + uv) * vec2(stepW, stepH);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform sampler2D markerTexture;
    
    varying vec2 vUv;
    
    void main(){
      vec4 col = texture(markerTexture, vUv);
      gl_FragColor = vec4(col.rgb, 1);
    }
  `
})

let io = new THREE.Mesh(ig, im);
scene.add(io);

let clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop((_) => {
  let t = clock.getElapsedTime();
  controls.update();
  im.uniforms.quaternion.value.copy(camera.quaternion).invert();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

function getMarkerTexture(size, amountW, amountH){
  let c = document.createElement("canvas");
  c.width = size;
  c.height = size;
  let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  const stepW = c.width / 32;
  const stepH = c.height / 64;
  
  ctx.font = "bold 40px Arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  
  let col = new THREE.Color();
  
  let counter = 0;
  for(let y = 0; y < amountH; y++){
    for(let x = 0; x < amountW; x++){
      
      let textX = (x + 0.5) * stepW;
      let textY = ((amountH - y - 1) + 0.5) * stepH;
      ctx.fillText(counter, textX, textY);
      
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + col.setHSL(Math.random(), 1, 0.5).getHexString();
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.strokeRect(x * stepW + 4, y * stepH + 4, stepW - 8, stepH - 8);
      
      counter++;
    }
  }
  
  let ct = new THREE.CanvasTexture(c);
  ct.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
  return ct;
}
</script>
```