# Three JS What is the fastest way to create text labels with CanvasTexture?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, label, game-development

My goal is to create thousands of labels via Three JS CanvasTexture.

I have some code (option A) but it currently runs slow for thousands of labels.

Option A creates a canvas for each label, whereas option B creates the canvas once. In option B, `var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d')` is outside the for loop.

Option A is slow but correctly displays the labels. Option B is faster but incorrectly displays the same label.

**Is there a way to make option B work?**

**Option A**

https://codepen.io/the_nectarine/pen/WNmBWbK

```
// Create the scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Create the camera
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var aspect = width / height;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0,0,5);

// Create the renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Create a shape
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
cube.rotation.set(15,15,0);
scene.add(cube);

// Create positions for labels
var parentObject = new THREE.Object3D();
var pointObjects = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    pointObjects.push({ x: i, y: j, z: 0 });
  }
}

// Create labels
var labelBaseScale = .002;

pointObjects.forEach(function (element, index) {
    var textToDisplay = index;
    var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width = 1000;
    ctx.canvas.height = 80;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    ctx.font = 100 + 'px monospace';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    ctx.translate(2, 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#747474';
    ctx.fillText(textToDisplay, 0, 0);

    var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(ctx.canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;

    var labelMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
      map: texture,
      transparent: true,
    });

    var label = new THREE.Sprite(labelMaterial);
    label.position.x = element.x;
    label.position.y = element.y;
    label.position.z = element.z;
    label.scale.x = ctx.canvas.width  * labelBaseScale;
    label.scale.y = ctx.canvas.height * labelBaseScale;
  
  parentObject.add(label);
});

scene.add(parentObject);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

**Option B**

https://codepen.io/the_nectarine/pen/JjzqVXG

```
// Create the scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Create the camera
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var aspect = width / height;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0,0,5);

// Create the renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Create a shape
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
cube.rotation.set(15,15,0);
scene.add(cube);

// Create positions for labels
var parentObject = new THREE.Object3D();
var pointObjects = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    pointObjects.push({ x: i, y: j, z: 0 });
  }
}

// Create labels
var labelBaseScale = .002;
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

pointObjects.forEach(function (element, index) {
    var textToDisplay = index;
    ctx.canvas.width = 1000;
    ctx.canvas.height = 80;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    ctx.font = 100 + 'px monospace';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    ctx.translate(2, 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#747474';
    ctx.fillText(textToDisplay, 0, 0);

    var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(ctx.canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;

    var labelMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
      map: texture,
      transparent: true,
    });

    var label = new THREE.Sprite(labelMaterial);
    label.position.x = element.x;
    label.position.y = element.y;
    label.position.z = element.z;
    label.scale.x = ctx.canvas.width  * labelBaseScale;
    label.scale.y = ctx.canvas.height * labelBaseScale;
  
  parentObject.add(label);
});

scene.add(parentObject);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76514035/1461008

Comment: You tagged `game-development`, IMO, the best technique to high fidelity rendering and performance: [*MDSF Bitmap fonts*](https://github.com/Chlumsky/msdf-atlas-gen).